# How to enable arrow keys in Kubuntu application launcher 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma, kickoff

I just switched from Kubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 and noticed that the application launcher is not behaving exactly the same.

In 11.10 I open the launcher with a keybinding, write the first letters of something that I want to run, and then use the arrow keys to choose from the list of applications the system found.

In 12.04 the arrow keys do not seem to work. If I write a few letters so that I get a list of choices pressing the arrow keys does absolutely nothing. I noticed that I can get to the list by pressing `ESC`, but this seems pretty unnecessary compared to how it used to work.

Does anyone know how to enable the arrow keys directly in the application launcher?

EDIT:
The specific launcher is the default launcher when installing Kubuntu Desktop 11.10 and 12.04. The name is `Kickoff` and it is a plasma launcher.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you mean...?**

Do you mean the KDE's Krunner ?

KDE Plasma launchers: http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma_application_launchers

The Krunner: http://userbase.kde.org/KRunner

The user interface: Command oriented

[image]

The up/down arrows should pick the choices.

The user interface: Task oriented

[image]

The left/right arrows will should pick the choices.

At here this seems to work with the Kubuntu 12.04.1 / KDE SC 4.8.4.

**If you mean the Krunner - then maybe...**

You could try to reset the Krunner settings to the default.

1) Stop the Krunner ( konsole/terminal ) :

```
kquitapp krunner
```

2) Rename/remove the Krunner config file: ~/.kde/share/config/krunnerrc

3) Restart the Krunner ( konsole/terminal ) :

```
krunner
```

4) Test

Comment: It seems that what I mean is a Plasma launcher, `Kickoff` to be specific. It is the default when installing Kubuntu Desktop in 11.10 and 12.04.